# Stored procedure to check if username exists

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure

So far I have this, but it always returns `1`

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `USER_EXISTS`(IN `USERNAME` VARCHAR(64) CHARSET utf8mb4)
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(user_id) IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END User_exists
  FROM `dbname`.`tablename`
 WHERE `username` = USERNAME
```

The goal is to perform this via AJAX so the user can see whether registration is likely to succeed before submitting their registration form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps doing a `COUNT` is better since it must be a number always

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `USER_EXISTS` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `USER_EXISTS`
(IN `GIVEN_USERNAME` VARCHAR(64) CHARSET utf8mb4)
BEGIN
    SET @User_exists = 0;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @found
    FROM `dbname`.`tablename`
    WHERE `username` = GIVEN_USERNAME;
    IF @found > 0 THEN
        SET @User_exists = 1;
    END IF;
    SELECT @User_exists;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

You could also write it as a function

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `USER_EXISTS` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `USER_EXISTS`
(`GIVEN_USERNAME` VARCHAR(64) CHARSET utf8mb4) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    SET @User_exists = 0;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @found
    FROM `dbname`.`tablename`
    WHERE `username` = GIVEN_USERNAME;
    IF @found > 0 THEN
        SET @User_exists = 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN @User_exists;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you could call the function to get a number

```
SET @x = USER_EXISTS('Synnyster');
SELECT USER_EXISTS('Synnyster');
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: Executing the function: `SET @p0 = 'Synnyster'; SELECT USER_EXISTS\` (@p0) AS \`USER_EXISTS\` ;` returns an empty result set

Comment: Remove the space between the function name and parenthesis : `SET @p0 = 'Synnyster'; SELECT USER_EXISTS(@p0) AS USER_EXISTS ;`

Comment: BTW did you implement it as a procedure or a function ?

Comment: I pasted the SQL you wrote for a function, and am executing via phpMyAdmin's Routines panel

Comment: The function returns 0 or 1. It should not return an empty set.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to change the dbname and tablename to my actuals. After fixing this it is returning 1 with all input

Comment: It always returns 1 because you had "WHERE `username` = USERNAME". I just changed in input parameter to `GIVEN_USERNAME`. Please try it now ...

Answer (score 0):

This can be a one-liner:  `RETURN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ... )`.  You get 0 or 1, not NULL.

At which point, why even create a function?  The query to run without the function:
`SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ... )`